# How to run Ansible play-book command from remote server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, autoscaling

I need to install and configure all new system start with auto-scaling in aws as per the requirements , like if it is a app server install nodejs with respective git code for deployment using with Ansible.

How Ansible identify a new system came up and need to do this all configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide from ansible docs how to handle autoscaling with Ansible: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_aws.html#autoscaling-with-ansible-pull

The problem on this approch is, that you need the whole provisining prozess on startup. This takes much time and is error prone.

A common solution is to build a custom AMI with all infrastructure needed for your service and only deploy your current code to this maschine.

A good tool to build custom AMIs is [Packer](https://www.packer.io/). A Guide for AWS is available here. https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html

Comment: common AMI we can use, but how can we do the deployment, it should be automatically and its autoscaled system, i have created a  script file and added at aws User data, script will take instance ip and add at inventory file , that inventory file copy to ansible server , then again login to ansible server and run a playbook using this inventory file.
 but i don't know why, it is not at all running even single line.    and error is getting `2019-02-27 06:07:29,130 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'b'sudo sh /home/ubuntu/sta'...'`

Comment: ## startup script `#!/bin/bash
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/' > ip.txt
a=`cat ip.txt` && sed  -i "2 i\\$a" inventory.cfg
scp -C -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem inventory.cfg ubuntu@172.31.31.215:/etc/ansible/inventory/  ##copy invemtory file to ansible
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem ubuntu@172.31.31.215 'ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/inventory/inventory.cfg /etc/ansible/air-hub.yml -b'
`